# Condor master node and workers only see the master node

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-processing, condor

I am trying to set a HTCondor batch system, but when I do `condor_status` it only shows the master in both the master and worker nodes. They both show this:

```
Name               OpSys      Arch   State     Activity LoadAv Mem

[master ip]   LINUX      X86_64 Unclaimed Idle      0.000  973

               Total Owner Claimed Unclaimed Matched Preempting Backfill  Drain

  X86_64/LINUX     1     0       0         1       0          0        0      0

         Total     1     0       0         1       0          0        0      0
```

`Condor_restart` on the master node works fine, but on the worker nodes yields this error:

```
ERROR
SECMAN:2010:Received "DENIED" from server for user unauthenticated@unmapped using no authentication method, which may imply host-based security.  Our address was '[ip address of master]', and server's address was '[ip address of worker]'.  Check your ALLOW settings and IP protocols.
```

Here are the config files:

of the master node:

```
CONDOR_HOST = [private ip of master]
DAEMON_LIST = COLLECTOR, MASTER, NEGOTIATOR, SCHEDD, STARTD
# to avoid user authentication
HOSTALLOW_READ = *
HOSTALLOW_WRITE = *
HOSTALLOW_ADMINISTRATOR = *
```

of the worker node:

```
CONDOR_HOST = [private ip of master]
DAEMON_LIST = MASTER, STARTD
# to avoid user authentication
HOSTALLOW_READ = *
HOSTALLOW_WRITE = *
HOSTALLOW_ADMINISTRATOR = *
```

I am allowing on the same security group:

```
All TCP    TCP      0 - 65535     
All    ICMP-IPv4   All     
SSH on port 22
```

This is how it looks like (security group ending in '6')
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue was running `condor_reconfig -full`. I just reinstalled it without doing that and using `systemctl restart condor` instead and it worked. If someone wants to bring some insight on why it was so please do so :)